# Translating MIPS assembly to a C statement

Tags: c, assembly, mips, statements

```
addi $s7, $s7, -4
add  $s7, $s7, $s1
lw   $s0, 4($s7)
```

Assume integer variables i and j are in registers $s0 and $s1. Assume base address of an integer array X is in register $s7.

So far I have this:

```
X = X - 4
X = X + j
i = X - 4 + j
```

Is this correct? I'm not overly sure so just looking for confirmation.

Comment: `lw` stands for "load word".

Comment: Actually, that code cannot be [reliably] translated into C. C arithmetic operations will (usually) be translated into unsigned MIPS instructions like addu/subu/addiu. This is due to the fact that the signed versions of the MIPS instructions trap on overflows - that's often ignored in C for signed types and always ignored in C for unsigned types. Seeing how `X` is likely a pointer, the unsigned instructions should be used.

Answer (score 4):

It is incorrect. Note that `lw` instruction reads a word from memory.

In C it would look something like

```
  //int *x;
  x--;            // addi $s7, $s7, -4 decrements pointer to x one element
  x = (int*)((char*)x + j);  // add $s7, $s7, $s1 increments the address pointed by x j elements
  i = *(x+1);     // lw $s0, 4($s7) reads the next element pointed by x
```

Addendum after OPs comment:

If `j = $s7` is multiple of 4 (note that each integer occupies 4 bytes), then it could be rewritten in C as `i = x[j/4]`.

Comment: So as C statement it could be something like:

i = X [ j + 1 ]

Comment: @yoshi105: not really. The problem is that each integer occupies 4 bytes, but the middle instruction adds an unknown number. **IF** j=`$s1` is multiple of 4 then it could be rewritten as i = X[j/4]

Comment: `(char*)x += j;` is wrong. It should be `x = (int*)((char*)x + j);` or if `j` is a multiple of `sizeof(int)`, `x += j/sizeof(int);`

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: changed that line. I believe the way it was written might not be "compile as-is" code but idea of what it did was mainly the same as it's written now.

Answer (score 0):

lw-->Load word

syntax:lw $t, offset($s)
operation: $t = MEM[$s + offset]; advance_pc (4);